# No adapter for endpoint in Spring Web Service Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I just cant figure out this error using Spring Web Services.  I believe I did everything correctly.

**Soap Error Response**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public void org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.PersonManagerSyncSoapBindingImpl.readPerson(org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.ReadPersonRequest,org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.Imsx_RequestHeaderInfoType,org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.holders.ReadPersonResponseHolder,org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.holders.Imsx_ResponseHeaderInfoTypeHolder)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

**Annotations**

```
@Endpoint  
public class PersonManagerSyncSoapBindingImpl implements org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.PersonManagerSyncPortType{


    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "readPersonRequest", namespace = "http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/pms2p0/wsdl11/sync/imspms_v2p0")
    @ResponsePayload
    public void readPerson(@RequestPayload org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.ReadPersonRequest parameters, org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.Imsx_RequestHeaderInfoType headerInfoParameters, @RequestPayload org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.holders.ReadPersonResponseHolder response, @RequestPayload org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.holders.Imsx_ResponseHeaderInfoTypeHolder headerInfoResponse) {
        response.value = new org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.ReadPersonResponse();
        headerInfoResponse.value = new org.imsglobal.www.services.lis.pms2p0.wsdl11.sync.imspms_v2p0.Imsx_ResponseHeaderInfoType();
    }
```

**spring-ws-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
            xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"  
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="*"></context:component-scan>
    <sws:annotation-driven/>

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="personServiceManagement"                                                           
        portTypeName="PersonManagerSyncPortType"                                                         
        locationUri="/endpoints/"                                                       
        targetNamespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/pms2p0/wsdl11/sync/imspms_v2p0">                               
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/xsd/PersonManagementService.xsd"/>                                                  
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're missing the return value. Spring-WS uses the method signature to map a request/response combination. For instance, I have the following operation in my generated WSDL:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetHiredCandidates">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:GetHiredCandidatesRequest" name="GetHiredCandidatesRequest"></wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:GetHiredCandidatesResponse" name="GetHiredCandidatesResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

To map a method on this operation the `ResponsePayload` and `RequestPayload` need to match the input and output defined in the WSDL:

```
@ResponsePayload
public GetHiredCandidatesResponse getKandidaat (@RequestPayload GetHiredCandidatesRequest) {
    ..

    return getHiredCandidatesResponse;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ha didnt notice that, but yea that makes sense.  I moved onto something else but I believe that is the problem.

Answer (score 44):

I had a similar error message. My problem was in request and response class that I generated from XSD. It missed @XMLRootElement annotation. This caused that description of operation (in WSDL) and description of implemented method (in Endpoint) did not match. **Adding JAXBElement to my endpoint method solved my problem.**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://foo.bar/books", localPart = "GetBook")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement<MyReponse> getBook(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<MyRequest>) {
    ...
```

See this blog for more details: [spring-ws: No adapter for endpoint](https://jbossadventure.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/spring-ws-no-adapter-for-endpoint/)

Comment: Thanks! This solved similar issue for me. I should have looked at `ObjectFactory` class, there are many JAXBElement objects used.

Comment: You Survived me! Thank you so Much!

Comment: Sir, you are a legend!

Comment: this works, but does not solve an invalid WSDL.  you must have both the input and output elements in the operation part.  the accepted answer below is the right solution, not this

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with Spring-ws and SOAPUI, and got it solved with the help of [No adapter for endpoint SWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683468/no-adapter-for-endpoint-sws)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue has gone after switching from the dependency on jdom to the jdom2.